# He movido de servidor una programación a medida en php

Tags: php, javascript, apache2

Acabo de mover una web de servidor. En el antiguo servidor funcionaba todo sin problemas pero en el nuevo no. El nuevo servidor es un dedicado apache 2. Las versiones de php están bien y toda la programación no se ha tocado. Me he dado cuenta que si elimino estas dos funciones entonces si funciona si las añado me arroja error 500 la web. ¿Saben porqué puede ser? Es como si el problema fuese javascript. El nuevo servidor es gestionado por Plesk 12.5

```
 function redireccionar_pagina($url) { ?>
 <script language="javascript">
 location.href="<? echo $url; ?>"
 </script><?   
 }
 function redireccionar_pagina_tiempo($url, $seg) {

  $seg = $seg*1000;
  ?>
   <script language="javascript">
    var pagina="<? echo $url; ?>"

    function redireccionar() {
       location.href=pagina
    }
    setTimeout ("redireccionar()", <? echo $seg; ?>);     
    </script>            
    <? 

     }
```

Comment: Vaya lío, eso es javascript que estás generando en PHP entiendo. Si pones el error que te da lo mismo podemos ver algo, pero el código está cogido con pinzas.

Answer (score 1):

Sustituye los `<?` por `<?php` o echa un vistazo a tu configuración de php, en el parámetro

> short_open_tag

Comment: era eso muchísimas gracias.